# Measure not hit for ChildClass in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am a new developer in Android. I am trying to develop an application in Android that displays **data in a table format**. My data scrolls both horizontally and vertically. My parent class contains **FrameLayouts which acts as rows**. **Inside each framelayout the CustomViews(extended from viewGroup) are populated which act as columns**.  Am maintaining the FrameLayouts in the parent panel in a list FrameLayoutList and the customViews inside that FrameLayout in a List CustomViewsList in the child class. Initially I have created the views in each FrameLayoutClass(rows) that will fit into the view. All works fine. But **Upon scrolling horizontally** I am creating a new CustomView and storing it in a list. Then adding the newly created items from the list into the FrameLayout in OnMeasure method. But the problem is the **OnMeasure is called for the parent, but is not called for the child FrameLayouts**. But I have called view.Measure(int,int) in my parent's OnMeasure. I tried all possible Invalidate(), postInvalidate(), InvalidateChild(view,Rect) and requestLayout. Nothing solved this. Can anyone help me on this?

This the code in my Parent's OnMeasure:

```
protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
int totalwidth = {some calculation...};
int totalheight = {some calculation...};
foreach (CustomFrameLayout row in this.FrameLayoutList) {
                    if (this.IndexOfChild(row) == -1)
                        this.AddView(row);
                    MeasureChild (row, 450, 750);
                    //row.Measure(450,750);
            }
SetMeasuredDimension(totalwidth,totalheight);
}
```

When the MeasureChild is hit I expect the ChildLayout's OnMesure to be called. It is called for the first time when loading. But when scrolling horizontally the code is hit but the ChildLayout's OnMeasure is not called.

This is the code in my child's OnMeasure:

```
protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int totalwidth = {some calculation...};
    int totalheight = {some calculation...};
    foreach (CustomView column in this.CustomViewsList) {
                    if (column.IsNew) {
                        if (this.IndexOfChild(row) == -1)
                            this.AddView(column);
                        column.Measure(50,50);
                    }
                }
    SetMeasuredDimension(totalwidth,50);
    }
```

Can anyone help me in this? how can get the OnMeasure called for the child class upon scrolling horizontally.

Comment: try to add super.onMeasure() in both methods

Comment: That worked for me. But It is making more measure calls for my child class. I dont know why by default the measure is hit 4 times and layout is hit 2 times in android. Now after this change, each CustomFrameLayout's measure is hit eight times for me. Moreover I dont understand how this works, as they would probably do invalidate the child, which I tried in my measure but didnt worked.

Comment: You need to add super.onMeasure() only once in the parent or child, i'm not sure exactly. But suppose, in the parent.

Comment: I have added the super.onMeasure() in the parent. That solved my problem. However now I have someother problems regarding the performance. And moreover am confused why the measure is hit four times? I know measure will be called 2 times, but it is called four times for me. I tried removing all my codes too. So it not bcos of my code probably. Do you know why?